# How to make a route function in Flask run every time a form is loaded

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a simple form with a password field in Flask that should have a limited amount of chances (10) to submit correctly. The problem is that even though I am subtracting the `chances` variable by 1 every time the submitted value isn't correct, `chances` is only subtracted once (it stops at 9), no matter how many times I submit the form and refresh the page.

Here's my route:

```py
@app.route('/administrator-login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def admin_login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/administrator-logout')
    form = AdminLogin()
    user = User.query.first()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if user.chances <= 0:
            return render_template(url_for('home'))
        if user and form.password.data == 'password': # I will hash the actual password later
            user.chances = 10
            login_user(user)
            return redirect('/hack-the-site-here')
        elif form.password.data != 'password':
            user.chances -= 1
    return render_template('admin_login.html', form=form, chances=user.chances)
```

And here's my form:

```py
class AdminLogin(FlaskForm):
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

The `'admin_login.html'` file

```html
<h3>Chances left: {{ chances }}</h3>
        <div class="mt-3">
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Admin Login</legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                            {% if form.password.errors %}
                                {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg") }}
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the `User` class:

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    chances = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

There is only one `User` object in the database and that shouldn't change.
Criticism and advice are accepted. 
I suspect that it has something to do with the way that `user.chances` is stored in the User object.
Do you need any other information? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the default value you are assigning to chances in the DB?

Comment: @ParthS007 10. That's how it's created.

Comment: in second `if` statement?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the value of the chance in DB also after making changes in the `chances` attribute.

```py
@app.route('/administrator-login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def admin_login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/administrator-logout')
    form = AdminLogin()
    user = User.query.first()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if user.chances <= 0:
            return render_template(url_for('home'))
        if user and form.password.data == 'password': # I will hash the actual password later
            user.chances = 10
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(user)
            return redirect('/hack-the-site-here')
        elif form.password.data != 'password':
            user.chances -= 1
            db.session.commit()
    return render_template('admin_login.html', form=form, chances=user.chances)
```

Comment: Apparently, `User` doesn't have that method. I get `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'save_to_db'`. Should I import it from somewhere or define it myself? How?

Comment: @PauloSchreiner I have changed that part. Check the updated answer.

Comment: As far as I know, the model I created has no save function whatsoever. I simply put `db.session.commit` after `user.chances -= 1` and `user.chances = 10` and now it's working as expected. Thanks!